# How to stop tasque creating a new task when clicking on any place

Tags: gnome, settings, task-management

Is it possible to stop [tasque](https://wiki.gnome.org/Apps/Tasque) creating a new (empty) task when I click? It is very annoying and I have to remind myself not to click every time I open tasque.

[image: tasque screenshot]

Comment: Note to the Close voters: Can you please leave a comment how this is unclear?

Comment: I think they may not use taskque before. I've add a screenshot above.

Comment: What is the version of Tasque are you using and how did you install it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've tested with tasque. I think it's by design. Check the tasque [news page in github](https://github.com/GNOME/tasque/blob/master/NEWS) where it is mentioned as a *feature* implemented since version 0.1.12. I suggest getting used to the "New Task" input field on toolbar.

Besides these, you can report this as a bug to the developers by going to the bug report page http://bugzilla.gnome.org/browse.cgi?product=Tasque

So, in short the answer is No, it's not possible. However you can try grabbing older version like 0.1.11 from somewhere else from building yourself (Though I don't know how feasible that would be).

Hope this helps.

Comment: Good luck with the report :)